# Can't install webmin (on CentOS 7) package updates

Tags: centos, upgrade, gpg, webmin

On CentOS7 and Webmin system:

I get this error when i try to install webmin package updates..:

None of the updates are working and giving this error:

```
Downloading packages:
warning: /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/home_csbuild_Perl/packages/perl-IO-Socket-SSL-1.982-1.2.noarch.rpm: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 04****: NOKEY
Retrieving key from http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/csbuild:/Perl/CentOS_7/repodata/repomd.xml.key


The GPG keys listed for the "Perl Modules (CentOS_7)" repository are already installed but they are not correct for this package.
Check that the correct key URLs are configured for this repository.


 Failing package is: perl-IO-Socket-SSL-1.982-1.2.noarch
 GPG Keys are configured as: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/csbuild:/Perl/CentOS_7/repodata/repomd.xml.key
```

I tried to change gpgcheck=0 but still getting same error.

I also tried:

```
gpg --quiet --with-fingerprint /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
```

and got this result:

```
pub  4096R/F4A80EB5 2014-06-23 CentOS-7 Key (CentOS 7 Official Signing Key) <security@centos.org>
      Key fingerprint = 6341 AB27 53D7 8A78 A7C2  7BB1 24C6 A8A7 F4A8 0EB5
```

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed this on one of my test servers.

The answer is on Redhat support
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/317083

Here is a summary:

It has to be verified that file /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release contains an unharmed publickey, the one used to verify the signature of Red Hat RPM packages. rpm -V redhat-release-server-6Server can be used to verify the integrity of the keyfile. If this shows that the file has been modified, either

An unharmed version of the file (i.e. from a different RHEL system) should be copied into this place
    Or the RPM package redhat-release-server-6Server has to be reinstalled, deploying a fresh version of file /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release. Since at this point the RHEL can not verify the signature of the package redhat-release-server-6Server, this check has to be suppressed with command line options.

After ensuring that the correct file /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release is in place, the following command should be used to make RPM aware of the key:

rpm --import /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release

This step will solve the issue.

As a further step it should be investigated why /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release was modified in the first place, i.e. deployment procedures need to get modified.

Root Cause

YUM/RPM on the system currently do not trust the key which was used to sign the RPM package which is about to be installed.

BTW
Try to fix your yum keys instead of installing with rpm. If you install with RPM then it will not handle dependencies and yum may break your webmin install on later yum updates. (if yum removes some dependency webmin needs)

Hope this helps!

Comment: i tried and got error:    rpm --import /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release
error: /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release: import read failed(2).

Comment: how can i fix my yum keys?

Comment: need to sudo to run. (probably are just wanted to cover bases)
Did you copy the file from another server where the repo works?
Also if you did copy the file check the file permissions, it must be root:root.

Comment: A bit more from RedHat

Diagnostic Steps

    This command will show which keys have been imported with 
rpm --import <key> previously
    # rpm -qa gpg-pubkey*

    The following command shows the keys a package is signed with:

    # yumdownloader rhncfg-client.noarch
    # rpm -qip rhncfg-client*rpm

following command verifies if the RHEL release key file was modified:

    # rpm -qf /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release
    # rpm -V redhat-release-server-6Server
    # gpg --quiet --with-fingerprint /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release

Comment: there is no file named RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release under  /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/         I use CentOS7 and webmin not redhat i guess

Comment: This is a key for another repo you have to find out what the repo/key file name is from your computer
look in: 
/etc/pki/rpm-gpg/

Comment: sorry but i really dont understand what you have tried and fixed ,plus the redhat solution link cannot open even by logging there